# get specified url from webpage using simplehtmldom

Tags: php

**i am trying to build simple php crawler**

for this purpose

i am getting constants of webpage using
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

after getting page data i get page  as bellow

```
include('simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.mypage.com');
foreach($html->find('a') as $e) 
echo $e->href . '<br>';
```

this works perfectly,and print all links on that page.

i only want to get some url like

```
/view.php?view=open&id=
```

i have wirtten function for this purpose

```
function starts_text_with($s, $prefix){
    return strpos($s, $prefix) === 0;
}
```

and use this function as

```
include('simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.mypage.com');
foreach($html->find('a') as $e) {
    if (starts_text_with($e->href, "/view.php?view=open&id=")))
    echo $e->href . '<br>';
}
```

but nothing return.

i hope you understand what i need.

```
i need to print only url which match that criteria.
```

Thanks

Comment: `xpath_match_all('//a/@href[contains(., "view.php?view=open")]', $html);` - https://gist.github.com/1358174

Comment: function starts_text_with($s, $prefix){
    return strpos(trim($s), $prefix) === 0;
}

Comment: Does it actually *start* with that text? Are you certain it doesn't have a leading `/` or event a full `http://somedomain.tld/` at the start?

Comment: also check whether the `&` is really an `&amp;` like it should be

Comment: dear @DaveRandom actually its starts with /

Comment: since you only want to know whether the string contains that portion, do `return strpos($s, $prefix) !== false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
include('simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.mypage.com');
foreach($html->find('a') as $e) {
    if (preg_match($e->href, "view.php?view=open&id="))
         echo $e->href . '<br>';
}
```

try this once.

refer [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)